# Chinese Zodiac Python Program

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python that will take user birthday input and output their western and chinese zodiac sign. Right now I am just trying to get the Chinese sign working. This is my code so far:

```
ZODIAC = [(1900, "Rat"), (1901, "Ox"), (1902, "Tiger"), (1903, "Rabbit"), (1904\
, "Dragon"), (1905, "Snake"), (1906, "Horse"), (1907, "Sheep"), (1908, "Monkey"\
), (1909, "Rooster"), (1910, "Dog"), (1911, "Pig")]

def getChineseZodiac(year):
    for i in ZODIAC:
        if (year - ZODIAC[i]) % 12 == 0:
            return ZODIAC[i]

year = input("Enter a year: ")
getChineseZodiac(year)
```

What I hope for this code to do is to run through each of those years in ZODIAC and find a match with modulus 0, and then return the string attached. But the error I get is `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. How do I solve this? 
Am I supposed to be using some other format for ZODIAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you are getting is because of the way you are indexing the list. `for i in ZODIAC` sets `i` to a member of ZODIAC, not to an index. You can't then use `ZODIAC[i]` and have it make sense. Instead, use `i` directly (in this case, by using `i[0]` and `i` in place of the two cases where you were using `ZODIAC[i]`). Or alternatively, if you do want to iterate over indexes, change your loop to use `for i in range(len(ZODIAC))`.

However, the whole problem can be simplified. Since the signs in your list are in order, you can do just a single modulus calculation and use it as an index into the list, rather than iterating over the list values and testing each one:

```
def getChineseZodiac(year):
    index = (year - ZODIAC[0][0]) % 12
    return ZODIAC[index]       # or ZODIAC[index][1], depending on what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

In `for i in ZODIAC`, i represents each element in the list ZODIAC, which is tuple. If you print i, you can see each tuple you put in the list.

In `ZODIAC[i]`, i is an indice which should be integer.

You can use `ZODIAC[i][0]` to obtain the year(int) and `ZODIAC[i][1]` to obtain the Chinese zodiac sign.

You can use a dictionary to do this.

```
ZODIAC = { 1900:"Rat", 1901:"Ox", 1902:"Tiger", 1903:"Rabbit", ... }
def getChineseZodiac(year):
    index = 1900 + (year - 1900) % 12
    return ZODIAC[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike JavaScript, iterating over a sequence in Python yields elements, not positions. Use `i` directly instead of using it to index `ZODIAC`.

```
>>> for i in ZODIAC:
...   print i
... 
(1900, 'Rat')
(1901, 'Ox')
(1902, 'Tiger')
(1903, 'Rabbit')
(1904, 'Dragon')
(1905, 'Snake')
(1906, 'Horse')
(1907, 'Sheep')
(1908, 'Monkey')
(1909, 'Rooster')
(1910, 'Dog')
(1911, 'Pig')
```

Comment: So are you implying that since it yields elements, I will not be able to use it in terms of finding a match with modulus 0?

Comment: Which part of the modulus code cares about the position in the list?

Comment: I.E. if user input is 2007, (1901 - ZODIAC) % 12 == 0 will not yield "Pig"?

Comment: Agh, you're right. Any hint as how to move forward from here?

Comment: Have you considered indexing the element? `>>> i[0]`
`1911`
`>>> i[1]`
`'Pig'`

Comment: @SeanKallungal try `if 1900+abs(i[0]-year)%12 == i[0]`